# Test htaccess REQUEST_URI for string, rebuild using RewriteRule for SEO

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I'm trying to get my .htaccess rules to test for a string pattern.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-z]{2}(-[a-z]{2})?/.+$ [NC]
```

If successful I need to dynamically rewrite it to the following for my PHP scripts.

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]{2}(-[a-z]{2})?)/([a-z0-9-]{1,128})[\.html]? /index.php?lng=$1&tpl=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

For example, these strings **should succeed** and preform the RewriteRule.

```
http://abc.com/ab
http://abc.com/ab-cd
http://abc.com/ab/some-page
http://abc.com/ab-cd/some-page
http://abc.com/ab-cd/some-page.html
```

These strings **should fail** and not perform the RewriteRule.

```
http://abc.com/1
http://abc.com/a
http://abc.com/12
http://abc.com/ab_
http://abc.com/ab-cd
http://abc.com/ab-cd/
```

In the case of the failures above they should simply continue along and either succeed or fail depending on the actual contents of the server.

**THE PROBLEM**

I placed a file on my server containing no code like so:

```
abc.com/asdf-asdf/test.html
```

and it keeps succeeding on the RewriteCond test.  Obviously I want it to fail, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "*Obviously I want it to fail...*" referring to this request `abc.com/asdf-asdf/test.html`. Where is that obvious pattern in your *"should fail*" examples? It doesn't seem so obvious to me, directory `asdf-asdf` is in none of your examples.

Comment: @faa, based on the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` on top of OP's post...

Comment: @Marty Thanks for the clarification. But, if those rules don't work how can they be used to explain what the OP is trying to achieve?

Comment: @faa I say obviously because the URI /asdf-asdf/ defiantly does not work with the RewriteCond I wrote above, meaning I want it to fail in this case and allow the webserver to finish calling the URI as requested.

Comment: NFM I found the problem.  I made a typo in my directory names on the server and my htaccess was processing ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?tpl=_error.  Still, that's good new because it appears all my code above is working perfectly.